# rails lists my entire database table, again, after already been listed as planned in my divs

Tags: ruby-on-rails, erb

My view re-lists all of my database table contents outside of the panel div where I intended to list them.

**The HTML**

```
<div class="row">
  <div class="small-12 large-12 columns"><h2>All recipes</h2></div>
  <%= @recipes.each do |x| %>
    <div class="small-2 large-4 columns">
      <div draggable="true" class="panel">
        <h2><small><%= x.name %></small></h2>
        <p><%= x.ingredients %></p>
        <p><%= x.how %></p>
        <p><%= x.nutrients %></p>
      </div>
    </div>
  <% end %>
</div>
```

**The Model**

```
class CreateRecipes < ActiveRecord::Migration
  def change
    create_table :recipes do |t|
      t.string :name
      t.text :ingredients
      t.text :nutrients
      t.text :how
      t.timestamps
    end
  end
end
```

**The Controller**

```
def index
  @recipes = Recipe.all
end
```

Comment: Uhm...you didn't post the model, you posted the migration that creates the table. Did you mean to do that?

Comment: You're also missing a `</div>` in your view that matches with your `<div draggable="true" class="panel">` so that could be causing some of your problems. Or when you copy-pasted something got out of order, perhaps. Hard to tell.

Comment: Here is the problem `<%= @recipes.each`.. See the linked post to know what it is problem..

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Ruby returns the contents of an array at the end of an `each`. You can see this by putting a loop in the Rails console:

```
@recipes.each { |r| puts r.name }
```

You'll get a list of names, but then you'll also see the array of recipes on the end.

In your template, your `each` statement is opened with `<%= @recipes.each do |x| %>`. ERB interprets the `=` as meaning you want the output of this statement to appear in the rendered template. You don't want that for the `each`. Try replacing the `=` with `-` (or simply taking it out).